# Reverse for viewname with arguments '(1,)' not found

Tags: python, django

Attempting to start the server and getting following exception (starting server leads to polls/index.html page):

> django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'detail' with
>   arguments '(1,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
>   ['$(?P[0-9]+)']

If I remove the following line fron index.html, the error is removed. But I don't get what the issue is. Even the ide prompts the current data. Found similar questions where the issue was with incorrect number of arguments which isn't the case with this. Please help.

Error line:

```
{% url 'polls:detail' q.id %}
```

index.html

```
{% for q in latest_question_list %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' q.id %}">{{ q.question_text }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

urls.py (inside polls app folder)

```
app_name = 'polls'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)', views.detail, name='detail'),
]
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('pub_date')[:5]
    context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)

def detail(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse(question_id)
```

urls.py (main)

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls'))
]
```

Comment: post `urls.py` here

Comment: @AstikAnand the urls.py is already posted above. Guessing you wanted both the one in the apps folder and the main one. Updated the question above.

Comment: Have you tried {% url 'detail' q.id %}?

Comment: @KyleHigginson Tried that and no difference.

Comment: @xyres I don't understand. Where have I included polls twice?

Comment: @xyres Just so I can go to that url be it http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/ or http://127.0.0.1:8000.

Comment: Please post your actual main urls. I am very much positive that you're using the same namespace twice.

Comment: @xyres yes please check my answer  :) you were on good lead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have included your poll URLs into the regex with stopping character $  (urls.py - main)

```
url(r'^$', include('polls.urls'))
```

This way there is no possible fulfilment for the following regex

```
 ['$(?P[0-9]+)']
```

If you still want to show polls index as your index site remove $ from line

```
url(r'^', include('polls.urls'))
```

Also, you have 2 inclusions of the same namespace and first catch of it is used ( index )

You can even see this if you change namespace for the polls URL

```
url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace='test'))
```

and use namespaced include as test:details ( this should work but I still recommend you to consolidate where you want to include poll URLs

Comment: Good answer. And it took so much time to solve this because the main urls posted by OP were not correct.